# Integration of postgreSQL on WAMP and phppgadmin

Tags: php, postgresql, integration, deprecated, phppgadmin

**I want to integrate postgresql with wamp for php and laravel development but       getting deprecated error when i logged in postgresql....**

Comment: So your question is? What is the error message?

Comment: If you use laravel framework, you doesn't need wamp server.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: postgresqlMinVer in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\classes\Misc.php on line 493

Comment: yeah but i am assigned to install wamp @OlegNurutdinov

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: postgresqlMinVer in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\classes\Misc.php on line 493  @Lithilion

Comment: Version of PostgreSQL not supported. Please upgrade to version or later. @Lithilion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classes>databases line 76 add

echo 'pgv ',$version;

Refresh your page and you probably see the number 11 - and that is not in the next switch statement.
Add a line for 11

Refresh your page - error is now in classes\database

Add a file for Postgres11 - it can be the same as fiel for 10, apart from version number.

Done.